# Can't find Intel Audio drivers

Tags: drivers, audio

Vendor Name: Intel Corporation

Chip Number: 82801H

Chip Description: Intel audio controller embedded with the 82801H chipset ( ICH8 chipset )

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't find anything with that information.  I'd need to know what motherboard you have and what operating system you are running.

If you're running Windows 2000, XP, Vista, or 7, visit this site in Internet Explorer http://www.intel.com/support/detect.htm?iid=dc_spotlight_home1

It will walk you through finding the correct drivers for any Intel devices in your system, including your audio controller.

Answer (score 0):

This chip was used in ibm thinkpads ( 61 series). Have a look here:
http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-67821 (vista)
http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-67816 (XP/2000)

Win 7 should have the driver abord. On Linux boxes the included ALSA driver should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the driver updates from the official site:

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-67853

1. Let Windows XP install all updates prior.
2. Install the Wireless USB driver. That enables the USB 3.0 to work.
3. Install the SoundMax audio driver.